# Pygame/Python: Can't create deepcopy of surfaces for room loading system (tl;dr at bottom)

Tags: python, pygame, deep-copy

tl;dr at the bottom. Most of this post is to give context to my problem. If that isn't needed, my main question is down below.

I am currently working on a pygame project (action adventure game) and I currently am working on stuff relating to object persistence and room transitioning. Basically, I want to create a system where I have a dictionary that contains all of the information about a particular room including the **images it uses and the objects that are in that room**.

My game has a dictionary that contains lists of the current objects that are updating and doing stuff in my game. Let's call this `instances`. Anytime I add an object to `instances`, it will appear in game. With that in mind, lets consider how loading the objects in a particular room actually works.
The way my system works is that I have a variable that is called `room` which contains a string that represents what room I am currently in. I have another dictionary that contains all of the objects within a room. Lets call this `room_dict`. `room_dict` would have the keys `"objects":[obj1,obj2]`. So based on the current value of `room`, it can access certain objects (i.e,`room_dict[room]["objects"]` would return a list of all of the objects in the current room).

Now that I've explained the basics of how it works, I have a method that actually knows when I have triggered a room transition (or rather, when the value of `room` is changed). When this happens, all of the objects existing in the room (that I was just in) are cleared from the `instances` dictionary. All of the objects from `room_dict[room]["objects"]` are added to `instances` so that they now appear in the game. Makes sense so far, right?

The main problem with this is that when objects in the `instances` dictionary (objects that are currently loaded) are updating, the objects that are in `room_dict[room]["objects"]` are also updated as well. This means that if I change the position of an enemy in one room and then leave the room and return, the object will be created at that position instead of the original position. So I tried doing `instances[list_of_enemies].append(copy.copy(enemy_object))` to add a copy of the object as well. This still didn't work though, and when I tried doing a `copy.deepcopy()`, the interpreter said that it was unable to serialize the object because one of its attibutes was a `pygame.Surface` object.

So in other words my main issue is that I want to make a copy of an object that contains a `pygame.Surface` as its attribute that doesn't reference the original object at all. How would I go about making a deepcopy with an object that has a `pygame.Surface` type attribute?

**tl;dr**: I want to make a copy of an object that has an attribute that is a `pygame.Surface` object but `copy.deepcopy()` doesn't work. Is there any other way to copy without referencing the original object?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the project is rather hefty, so it would be quite difficult to give code for context. I personally don't think it is needed, but I thought I'd put this out anyways. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You really *must* provide a [mcve]. It seems that all you would need to do is create an object with an attribute that is a `pygame.Surface` and then show what happens with `deepcopy`. You don't need all the rest. In any case, the `copy.deepcopy` implementation relies on the pickling interface to copy objects that don't define a `__deepcopy__` method. So, it may be that `pygame` hasn't adequately supported copying. I'm not sure how this would be handled idiomatically in pygame

Comment: `TypeError: can't pickle pygame.Surface objects` is the error that I get if I simple do `s = copy.deepcopy(pygame.Surface((1,1)))`

Comment: So, looking it up, it seems that `pygame.Surface` objects have a `.copy` method. you could try rolling your own copying function, to handle this specific case, using `surface.copy()`

Comment: `Surface.copy()` returns a surface, and that still cannot be serialized, so we're back where we started

Comment: *But you don't need to serialize it*. You need to copy it. I'm saying, write your own copy function. You almost certainly don't need to define a generic deepcopy, you know the structure of your objects.

Comment: You should just stop trying to deepcopy/copy/pickle Surfaces. It's a waste of memory anyway, at least if you don't generate unique images dynamically. You could e.g. lazy load the images. Maybe show an example of how your `room_dict` looks like so someone can make a reasonable suggestion. I don't think copying the images is usefull at all.

Comment: @sloth yes, I don't know pygame, but I suspect this is an XY problem.

Comment: It's not about copying a surface alone, its about being able to copy the entire object, which happens to have a `pygame,Surface` as one of its attributes. I want to copy an object from one dictionary to another with the object that I copied from to be preserved and unchanged while the copy can change and does not reference the original object

Comment: is there a way to make a copy that doesnt reference the original object without using `deepcopy()`

Comment: @Protolaser28 Yes, I understand you problem. But I think we need more details to come up with a good solution. So, is the object you want to copy just some kind of template you want to apply to create new stuff in your game? Do you really need different surfaces in your objects or can they be shared? Are you loading the images from disk or do you create them dynamically?

Comment: @Protolaser28 *yes*. You have to *implement your own function*. Or perhaps subclass `pygame.Surface` and implement a `__deepcopy__` method that simply does `return self.copy()`, then use that. Those are two options.

Comment: @sloth I load all of the data for my rooms as a json file from a level editor and read it using the json module. After reading what all of the objects in the room are, I create the objects and store them in a dictionary for that specific room. This is so that I only have to load the room's json information once instead of loading it over again. Once I go into a specific room, I want the program to create a copy of each of the objects at a desired position. If I leave the room and return, the objects should be recreated again at the original position it was at

Comment: so if i have an enemy at [0,0] in my room and it moves to [100,100] and I leave the room while the enemy is at [100,100], I want to make it so that I load in a version of the enemy that was at the [0,0] position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to create your objects from your json file everytime you need a new copy instead of creating the objects beforehand.

Or you could change your copy method: implement `__deepcopy__` and/or `__copy__` and copy the attributes of your objects without the `image` attribute, maybe just create a new instance.

Simple example:

```
import pygame
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import cycle

# an implementation of something in our game
class Cloud(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, speed):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pos
        self.speed = speed
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 20))
        self.image.set_colorkey((11, 12, 13))
        self.image.fill((11, 12, 13))
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, 'white', self.image.get_rect())
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=self.pos)

    def update(self):
        super().update()
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().colliderect(self.rect):
            self.rect.right = 0

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        # just create a new instance 
        return Cloud(self.pos, self.speed)

# the definition of our game world
game_data = {
    'WORLD_A': {
        'color': 'lightblue',
        'objects': pygame.sprite.Group(Cloud((50, 50), 1))
    },
    'WORLD_B': {
        'color': 'red',
        'objects': pygame.sprite.Group(Cloud((100, 100), 2), Cloud((80, 30), 3))
    },

}

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

keys = cycle(game_data.keys())

# happy deepcopying
current = deepcopy(game_data[next(keys)])

while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # happy deepcopying
            current = deepcopy(game_data[next(keys)])
            
    screen.fill(current['color'])
    current['objects'].update()
    current['objects'].draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Another solution is to lazy load the images and look them up only when needed so you don't need to copy them. Here's a simple example:

```
... see example above ...

# load/create all images once and store them in a dict
def create_cloud_image():
    image = pygame.Surface((50, 20))
    image.set_colorkey((11, 12, 13))
    image.fill((11, 12, 13))
    pygame.draw.ellipse(image, 'white', image.get_rect())
    return image

images = {
    'cloud': create_cloud_image()
}

# a simple sprite that lazy loads its image
class CopyableActor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_key, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.pos = pos
        self.image_key = image_key

    def init_image(self):
        self.image = images['cloud']
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=self.pos)

    def update(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'image'):
            self.init_image()

# an implementation of something in our game
class Cloud(CopyableActor):
    def __init__(self, pos, speed):
        super().__init__('cloud', pos)
        self.speed = speed

    def update(self):
        super().update()
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
        if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().colliderect(self.rect):
            self.rect.right = 0


... see example above ...
```

[image]